# Observe only changes made with KVO

Tags: swift, cocoa, avplayer, key-value-observing

I have an AVPlayer object, and I'm observing the state changes using KVO; Changes to .timeControlStatus, which tells you whether the AVPlayer is playing, stopped, loading, or paused.

The problem is the AVPlayer sets the .timeControlStatus property to .waitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate (means the file is loading) many, many times while the file is loading. I only want to be notified on **the first** change to loading, not subsequent settings. My observer is set up like this:

```
// watch .timeControlStatus
    playerStatusToken = player?.observe(\.timeControlStatus, options: [.new], changeHandler: { [weak self] player, change in
        if player.timeControlStatus == AVPlayer.TimeControlStatus.paused {
            if self?.playerItemActive == false {
                print("playback stopped")
                self?.prevID = self!.currentID
                self?.currentID = 0
                self?.currentURL = nil
                self?.playState = .stopped
            }
            else {
                print("playback paused")
                self?.playState = .paused
            }
        }
        else if player.timeControlStatus == AVPlayer.TimeControlStatus.playing {
            self?.playState = .playing
        }
        else if player.timeControlStatus == AVPlayer.TimeControlStatus.waitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate {
            self?.playState = .loading
        }
    })
```

Is there a way I can only respond to changes? I don't wan't to know if the .timeControlStatus is set to the same value as last time. Is there a way to do that (aside from keeping a variable called "lastStatus", and comparing to that).

Answer (score 1):

Using `Combine` allows you to observe changes and filter out duplicate values out of the box

```
// retain var in your class
var cancellable: Cancellable?


// observe changes
cancellable = player?.publisher(for: \.timeControlStatus)
    .removeDuplicates()
    .sink() { 
        // your change handler 
    }
```